# git with ssh keeps asking for passphrase everytime

Tags: ssh, git, dot-files, gitlab

I'm using a git bare repository for managing dotfiles, and some other repositories for custom DWM build and all. I use SSH for pushing and pulling from git, but it keeps asking me my SSH passphrase every time try to push or pull. i have already tried

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

then

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and its added successfully, but no luck I am missing something?

Comment: you set your public key in git ? configure git user using `git config` ?

Comment: Yes I my pasted my public key `id_rsa.pub` to gitlab -> settings -> SSH keys and i did `config config --global user.name "apoorv569"` and `config config --global user.email "xxxx@email.com"` and for other repositories also i did the same but `git config` instead of `config config`. `config`  is aliased to `config='/usr/bin/git --git-dir=/home/apoorv/dotfiles --work-tree=/home/apoorv'` as mentioned here - https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/dotfiles

Comment: and you use aliased `config` to pull/push files also ? (well obviously, either you would have been rejected from git)

Comment: yes for dotfiles I use the alias `config` and for other repositories, i cd into the folder and use regular `git`

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26371/ssh-prompts-for-password-despite-ssh-authorized-keys) could be related. Cross site: [Git keeps prompting me for a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773181/git-keeps-prompting-me-for-a-password?page=1&tab=trending#tab-top) on Stackoverflow or [How to make git not prompt for passphrase for ssh key?](https://superuser.com/questions/1010542/how-to-make-git-not-prompt-for-passphrase-for-ssh-key) on Superuser

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken but if you set a passphrase when you set up the ssh keys then you always will need to enter it.   The passphrase encrypts the private key so if it is compromised it still can't be used without knowing the passphrase.

Comment: so there is no way, i can store this passphrase somewhere or make it remember that its me, so i don't have to enter the passphrase every time i want to push or pull. someone told me that its possible.

Comment: See if your OS has or supports ssh-agent.   You might be able to use that to auto enter the passphrase.

Comment: original post already state that, I have already tried using `eval $(ssh-agent)` and `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: When the ssh-add is done does it ask for your passphrase?

Comment: When I ran the command `ssh-add` for the first time, it asked `Enter passphrase for /home/apoorv/.ssh/id_rsa:`, after that it said, `Identity added: /home/apoorv/.ssh/id_rsa (email@email.com)`, then I also double checked `ssh-add -l` to list all added identities, and there was the one that I added.

Comment: That seems like it should work.  Afraid the only other way I can think of is to re-generate the ssh keys without a passphrase.

Comment: Is there something that I need to add to `~/.ssh/config` maybe?